# Complexity of converting a set to a frozenset in Python

Tags: python, set, time-complexity, frozenset

What is the computational complexity of "freezing" a set in Python?

For example, does the second line in

```
a = {1,2,3}
b = frozenset(a)
```

require O(n) time? Or is it simply a "view" created in constant time?

Comment: It is not a view, since if you later `.add(..)` something to `a`, `b` is not updated.

Comment: The construction is linear in the number of elements the iterable of the parameter has.

Comment: So construction is *O(n)*. Insertion can go as bad as *O(n)* for a single element, but the *amoritzed*  cost is *O(1)*.

Comment: Why not simply create a large set and try it?  It should be very obvious from a single test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` is not a view of `a`. You can check this via [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = a

id(a) == id(b)  # True

b = frozenset({1, 2, 3})

id(a) == id(b)  # False
```

Hence a change in `b` will *not* be reflected in `a`. You can, of course, test this yourself. Since `frozenset` takes an iterable as an argument, it must iterate over each argument. This is an O(*n*) process.

As an aside, there's nothing special about `frozenset`, even creating a `set` from a `set` has O(*n*) time complexity:

```
for i in [10**5, 10**6, 10**7]:
    a = set(range(i))
    %timeit set(a)

100 loops, best of 3: 3.33 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 30.2 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 421 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

While the complexity doesn't change, the runtime *is* different depending whether the input to the frozenset initializer is an iterator, list, tuple, or set.

I ran the following shell script in ZSH:

```
for i in 5 6 7
do
    for f in '' 'list' 'tuple' 'set'
    do
        echo "i=$i f=$f"
        python -m timeit -s "x=$f(range(10**$i))" 'frozenset(x)'
    done
done
```

Which produced the following results on my laptop using Python 3.11.2:

```
i=5 f=
100 loops, best of 5: 2.37 msec per loop
i=5 f=list
200 loops, best of 5: 1.31 msec per loop
i=5 f=tuple
200 loops, best of 5: 1.41 msec per loop
i=5 f=set
500 loops, best of 5: 609 usec per loop
i=6 f=
10 loops, best of 5: 25.6 msec per loop
i=6 f=list
20 loops, best of 5: 14.4 msec per loop
i=6 f=tuple
20 loops, best of 5: 14.5 msec per loop
i=6 f=set
50 loops, best of 5: 5.97 msec per loop
i=7 f=
1 loop, best of 5: 256 msec per loop
i=7 f=list
2 loops, best of 5: 144 msec per loop
i=7 f=tuple
2 loops, best of 5: 148 msec per loop
i=7 f=set
5 loops, best of 5: 76.4 msec per loop
```

**It was consistently fastest to initialize the frozenset from an input set**; initializing from a list and tuple were about tied; and initializing directly from the `range` iterator was slowest (probably because it was including the iteration, which happened during setup for the others).

This indicates to me that frozenset might be able to reuse more of the state of a set—even if it has to make a copy to remain immutable. For other iterable types, frozenset may have to build its state from scratch.

---

One of the comments suggested that it might just be that a set's iterator is faster than the iterator for a tuple or list. Here's the same script, but this time simply iterating rather than building a `frozenset`:

```
for i in 5 6 7
do
    for f in '' 'list' 'tuple' 'set'
    do
        echo "i=$i f=$f"
        python -m timeit -s "x=$f(range(10**$i))" 'for _ in x: pass'
    done
done
```

And here are the results:

```
i=5 f=
200 loops, best of 5: 1.52 msec per loop
i=5 f=list
500 loops, best of 5: 419 usec per loop
i=5 f=tuple
1000 loops, best of 5: 359 usec per loop
i=5 f=set
500 loops, best of 5: 688 usec per loop
i=6 f=
20 loops, best of 5: 15 msec per loop
i=6 f=list
50 loops, best of 5: 4.34 msec per loop
i=6 f=tuple
100 loops, best of 5: 3.64 msec per loop
i=6 f=set
50 loops, best of 5: 6.3 msec per loop
i=7 f=
2 loops, best of 5: 147 msec per loop
i=7 f=list
5 loops, best of 5: 43.5 msec per loop
i=7 f=tuple
5 loops, best of 5: 38.1 msec per loop
i=7 f=set
5 loops, best of 5: 58.4 msec per loop
```

(Note: This was run on a different machine than the previous result, so the absolute numbers are probably not comparable. I did test to make sure the previous result still holds. All we care about in the following are the relative results.)

Simply iterating over a set was *significantly* slower than iterating over a list or a tuple. That makes complete sense to me—lists and tuples are backed by arrays, so you really can't do much better for iterating.

Even if sets are also stored as arrays, they'll be sparse due to hashing. Python presumably either keeps a separate internal list for iteration, or skips the empty slots.

Yet, despite being slower to iterate, it's still *faster* to initialize a frozenset from a set.

Comment: `frozenset` has to iterate in every case; the only difference is in what it's iterating (a `range_iterator`, a `list_iterator`, a `tuple_iterator`, or a `set_iterator`). A `range_iterator` does, however, need to "generate" each element on demand, while the other three are simply walking through an underlying container which already contains all the elements.

Comment: @chepner how does your simplistic iteration model explain the fact that initializing from a set is significantly faster than initializing from the other sequences?

Comment: It doesn't really, only that `set_iterator`s are in some way faster. It *seems* like computing the next element in a range is somehow slower than advancing a pointer in memory to fetch the next element in a list/tuple/set. I'm mostly just pointing out a slight inaccuracy in the OP's parenthetical remark.

Comment: @chepner I added a section discussing iteration. It's actually slower to iterate over a set, which even more strongly suggests something else is going on. And yeah, the raw range call is an outlier—it has to actually run the function.